# StackOverflowError while navigating between activities of ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-activity, stack-overflow, activitygroup, activity-finish

I am making an application with tabs. In that app same `TabView` is to be shown in multiple activities in hierarchy. For that i used `ActivityGroup`.

In my application i can navigate from first activity containing tab to its child activity and can come back to previous activity by pressing a button in child activity. While navigating between these two activities, i get  StackOverflowError after few navigations. 
I tried flag

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

but it doesn't help.
I also tried

```
finish()
```

but it finishes whole `ActivityGroup`. 
Then i tried method

```
finishActivityFromChild()
```

but still getting same error.

This is my code for moving from first activity containing tabs to its child-

```
intent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activity2", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); 
setContentView(view);
finishActivityFromChild(getCurrentActivity(), 0);
```

And the same code i am using for coming back to parent activity on click of a button-

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    intent = new Intent(context, ParentActivity.class);
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activity1", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); 
setContentView(view);
finishActivityFromChild(getCurrentActivity(), 0);
}
```

Now i have no idea what to do for this problem. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think some code would help here. If I were you, I would try to plent printouts of functions called, to see what function is being called recuresively that might cause the stack overflow. (Some breakpoints might also do the trick)

Comment: According to the API finishActivityFromChild() is called in the parent when the child finishes its activity, you probably shouldn't invoke it explicitly. Have you tried simply using prints or breakpoints to find out what circular calls are being made?